# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i p_i=1$ if and only if $p_i=1$ when $0<a_i<1$, $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$, $0\leq p_i\leq 1$

Tags: summation, proof-writing

Consider $n$ real numbers $0<a_i<1$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1$

Consider other $n$ real numbers $0\leq p_i\leq1$.

Could you help me to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i p_i=1$ if and only if $p_i=1$ $\forall i$? If you believe that the statement is not correct could you give some sufficient conditions for it to be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there $\sum a_jp_j=1$ and there is some $i$ such that $p_i<1$. Without lose of generality, suppose $i=1$. Then $$1=a_1p_1+a_2p_2+...+a_np_n<a_1+a_2p_2+...+a_np_n\le\sum a_j=1$$. This contradiction shows that $p_j=1$ for all $j$.

On the other hand, if $p_j=1$ for all $j$, then $\sum a_jp_j=\sum a_j=1$ by hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
1-\sum_i a_ip_i=\sum_ia_i-\sum_ia_ip_i=\sum_ia_i(1-p_i).\tag1
$$
The RHS is a sum where every term is non-negative. If the LHS is zero then each term $a_i(1-p_i)$ must be zero. What do you conclude about each $p_i$?

(The converse assertion follows from (1) as well.)

Answer (score 2):

For the forward direction, we use the contrapositive.
Suppose $p_{i_0} < 1$ for some $i_0$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $i_0 = 1$, by reordering the summands. Then
$$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i p_i = a_1 p_1 + \sum\limits_{i = 2}^n a_i p_i < a_1 + \sum\limits_{i = 2}^n a_i = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i = 1.
$$

For the reverse direction, suppose $p_i = 1$ for all $i$.
Then
$$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i p_i = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n a_i = 1
$$
by assumption, so we are done.

Answer (score 1):

I like to solve question like yours...: you can start out by observing that: $0 \leq a_ip_i \leq a_i$,and taking sum you have: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_ip_i \leq \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$. Can you take it from here?